# SQL ISDATE returns false for string formatted as ISO w/timezone (127)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

I'm attempting to take a string, determine if it is a date (date time or time) and then convert it to the respective data type with the SQL server convert format constants.  However, I'm having a lot of trouble with 127 "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ" in that ISDATE returns false for a string formatted this way.

```
SELECT ISDATE('2018-07-21 15:14:00.5206914 -06:00') -- returns false
```

Why is that? And is there any build in sql server function I'm not aware of that can test to see if this is a valid date string?

Comment: What's your dbms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`isdate` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) accepts certain dates (depending on the date format and language), but never a `datetimeoffset`.  The offset is the `-06:00` part at the end of your example.

You could use [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with style 120 (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)` ODBC canonical) instead:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2018-07-21 15:14:00.5206914 -06:00', 120);
-->
2018-07-21 15:14:00.5206914 -06:00
```

The `try_convert` function will return `null` if the passed expression is not a valid `datetimeoffset`.